# How to Change Port Number in cadvisor and node-exporter of Prometheus Monitoring

Tags: docker, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator, prometheus-node-exporter

Below is the showing in prometheus URL when i click on target.

**cadvisor (0/1 up) and node-exporter (0/1 up) are showing in Prometheus URL**

Here is the my filename.yml file

```
version: '3.2'

services:

  prometheus:
       image: prom/prometheus:latest
#       container_name: monitoring_prometheus
       command:
         - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
         - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
         - '--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries'
         - '--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles'
       volumes:
         - /Prometheus/alert.rules:/etc/prometheus/alert.rules
         - /Prometheus/container.yml:/etc/prometheus/container.yml
         - /Prometheus/diskusage.yml:/etc/prometheus/diskusage.yml
         - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
       ports:
         - 9090:9090

  node-exporter:       
       image: prom/node-exporter:latest
#       container_name: monitoring_node_exporter       
       volumes:       
         - /proc:/host/proc:ro       
         - /sys:/host/sys:ro       
         - /:/rootfs:ro       
       ports:
         - 9091:9091
       command:       
         - '--path.procfs=/host/proc'       
         - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'       
         - '--path.rootfs=/host'       
         - '--collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points="^(/rootfs|/host|)/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc)($$|/)"'       
         - '--collector.filesystem.ignored-fs-types="^(sys|proc|auto|cgroup|devpts|ns|au|fuse\.lxc|mqueue)(fs|)$$"'       


  cadvisor:
       image: google/cadvisor:latest
#       container_name: monitoring_cadvisor
       ports:
         - 9092:9092
       volumes:
         - /:/rootfs:ro
         - /var/run:/var/run:rw
         - /sys:/sys:ro
         - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro


  grafana:
       image: grafana/grafana:latest
#       image: grafana-custom:latest
#       container_name: monitoring_grafana   
       volumes:
         - grafana-data:/var/lib/grafana
#         - ./data/grafana:/var/lib/grafana
#         - ./grafana/provisioning:/etc/grafana/provisioning
#         - ./defaults.ini:/usr/share/grafana/conf/defaults.ini
       ports:
         - 3000:3000
       environment:
         - "GF_SMTP_ENABLED=true" 
         - "GF_SMTP_HOST=smtp.gmail.com:465" 
         - "GF_SMTP_USER=test@gmail.com" 
         - "GF_SMTP_PASSWORD=xxxxxx" 

  alertmanager:
       image: prom/alertmanager
#        privileged: true
       volumes:
         - ./alertmanager.yml:/alertmanager.yml
       command:
         - '--config.file=/alertmanager.yml'
       ports:
         - '9093:9093'
 
  karma-alert-dashboard:
#       image: cloudflare/unsee
       image: lmierzwa/karma:latest
       environment:
#         - "ALERTMANAGER_URIS=default:http://alertmanager:9093"
         - "ALERTMANAGER_URI=http://alertmanager:9093"
       ports:
         - '9094:9094'


volumes:
  grafana-data:
```

I have deploy 5 docker service through docker stack -c filename.yml test, All services and docker container are UP.

First 3 are connected together and are working fine

> ```
> Grafana      =  http://SERVERIP:3000/ - 3000  
> Prometheus   =  http://SERVERIP:9090/ - 9090  
> AlertManager =  http://SERVERIP:9093/ - 9093
> ```

Last 3 are Not connected together and are Not working fine because of port issue in docker container and in docker service also

> ```
> Karma        =  http://SERVERIP:9094/ - 8080  
> Node Exporter=  http://SERVERIP:9100/ - 9100  
> CAdvisor     =  http://SERVERIP:8080/ - 8080
> ```

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

When i check ports number 3 services are showing different in terminal but in my filename.yml everything is correct can anyone let me what is the issue and where i'm wrong

When i check logs of 3 docker container

1. docker logs cadvisor

```
Could not configure a source for OOM detection, disabling OOM events: open /dev/kmsg: no such file or directory
```

2. node-exporter is not showing any logs.
3. Here is the logs of lmierzwa/karma

```
level=info msg="Version: v0.86-83-gf5e5269f"
level=info msg="Configured Alertmanager source" name=default proxy=false readonly=false uri=http://alertmanager:9093
level=info msg="Initial Alertmanager collection"
level=info msg="Pulling latest alerts and silences from Alertmanager"
level=info msg="Collecting alerts and silences" alertmanager=default
level=info msg="GET request" timeout=40 uri=http://alertmanager:9093/metrics
level=info msg="Upstream version" alertmanager=default version=0.22.2
level=info msg="Got silences" alertmanager=default duration=0.000204419 silences=0
level=info msg="Detecting ticket links in silences" alertmanager=default silences=0
level=info msg="Collected alert groups" alertmanager=default duration=0.000201856 groups=0
level=info msg="Deduplicating alert groups" alertmanager=default groups=0
level=info msg="Processing deduplicated alert groups" alertmanager=default groups=0
level=info msg="Merging autocomplete hints" alertmanager=default hints=0
level=info msg="Collection completed"
level=info msg="Done, starting HTTP server"
level=info msg="Starting HTTP server" address=[::]:8080
level=info msg="Pulling latest alerts and silences from Alertmanager"
level=info msg="Collecting alerts and silences" alertmanager=default
level=info msg="GET request" timeout=40 uri=http://alertmanager:9093/metrics
level=info msg="Upstream version" alertmanager=default version=0.22.2
level=info msg="Got silences" alertmanager=default duration=0.000155633 silences=0
```

Comment: FYI it's __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrapping, 'Scrapping' means throwing things away like rubbish.

Answer (score 5):

To change port number, this is the example for cadvisor and node exporter

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  cadvisor:
    image: google/cadvisor:latest
    ports:
    - 9092:9092
  ...
    command:
    - '-port=9092'
    ...
  
  node-exporter:       
   image: prom/node-exporter:latest      
   ...
   ports:
   - 9091:9091
   command:       
     - ' --web.listen-address=9091'       
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your docker configuration file, you're not mapping the right port on those three services :

- node_exporter
- cadvisor
- karma-alert-dashboard

You need to map the ports that are exposed by those docker image.
For example, for the node_exporter, if you want to access it on port `9091` of your VM, you'll have something like this :

```
       ports:
         - 9091:9100 # node_exporter works on port 9100 by default
```

If you want to know wich port are exposed by those images, you can just have a look at the github documentation of each project or do a `docker image inspect your_image`

Comment: I have change the port in 3 services but still showing the default port in docker container and i have inspect the docker image it showing me 
```
"AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "9090/tcp": {}
            },
```

Comment: For which image does it show `9090` ? This port is the one used by prometheus. If you haven't changed the other images, which does not seems to be the case based on your configuration, none of the other images are using `9090` based on their documentation.

Comment: prometheus are using 9090 port.

i want to change port number of karma-alert-dashboard container but  it is taking 8080 default i follow the documentation of https://github.com/prymitive/karma/blob/main/docs/CONFIGURATION.md 

Here i have add export listen under env but still show 8080 in container
```
karma-alert-dashboard:
#       image: cloudflare/unsee
       image: lmierzwa/karma:latest
       environment:
         - "export LISTEN_PORT=9094"
         - "ALERTMANAGER_URI=http://alertmanager:9093"
       ports:
         - '9094:9094'
```